# Bitwise-OR the elements of a list in python using lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I use the lambda function this way to bitwise-OR all the elements in the list?

```
lst = [1, 1, 1]
f = lambda x: x | b for b in lst
```

When I do this I get a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
f = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, lst)
```

`reduce` accepts a binary function and an iterable, and applies the operator between all elements starting from the first pair. 
Note: in Python 3  it moves to the [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) module.

You can also use the [`or_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) function from the `operator` module instead of writing the lambda yourself:

```
from operator import or_
f = reduce(or_, lst)
```